# Esper: Chaining property access and method calls in EPL queries

Tags: method-chaining, esper, epl

I am currently struggling to get some Esper EPL queries to work. The queries are looking like this:

```
select a.center.distance(b.center) as delta
from pattern [
    every-distinct(a.id, b.id) (
        a=org.example.PositionEvent -> b=org.example.PositionEvent
    )
]
```

When I try to compile this into an `EPLStatement` via `EPAdministrator.createEPL()` it throws the following exception:

> com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementException: Error starting statement: Could not load class by name 'a.center', please check imports

If I modify the event classes and the query to read like this

```
select a.distance(b) as delta
from pattern [
    every-distinct(a.id, b.id) (
        a=org.example.PositionEvent -> b=org.example.PositionEvent
    )
]
```

it compiles just fine. Esper seems to interpret `a.center.distance(...)` as a class name followed by a static method invocation, while it interprets `a.distance(...)` as a method call on the object `a`.

How can I make Esper interpret my original query as intended (i.e. as a property access followed by a method invocation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually simple and straightforward (yet a little bit ugly): Use parentheses, just like you do everywhere else when something could be ambiguous. So to make that first query work, write it like this:

```
select (a.center).distance(b.center) as delta
from pattern [
    every-distinct(a.id, b.id) (
        a=org.example.PositionEvent -> b=org.example.PositionEvent
    )
]
```

In this case, it actually looks even slightly more readable with the added parentheses.